# code sample to create own keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have searched around for making a sample on creating my custom keyboard but nothing seemed to help. So Please provide me a code sample to create my custom keyboard

please help me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YourKeyboard.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol YourKeyboardControllerDelegate
-(void) buttonTapped: (int) ASCIICode;
@end

@interface YourKeyboardViewController : UIViewController
{
    id<YourKeyboardControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic,weak) id<YourKeyboardControllerDelegate> delegate;


@end
```

YourKeyboard.m :

```
#import "YourKeyboardViewController.h"

@implementation YourKeyboardViewController
@synthesize  delegate;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return NO;
}

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    if (delegate != nil)
    {
        [delegate buttonTapped:[sender tag]];
    }
}
```

Now - make your own .xib file with any view you want. Connect every button with "buttonTapped" method. Assign proper ASCII code as a tag for each button. I am using this solution and everything works fine.

Usage:
You are creating view controller as a YourKeyboardControllerDelegate.

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <YourKeyboardControllerDelegate> 
{
   YourKeyboardViewController *keyboard
}
```

and in .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  keyboard = [[YourKeyboardViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"nib file for keyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    keyboard.delegate = self;

  // connecting new keyboard to textfield
  someTextField.inputView = keyboard.view; 
}


-(void) buttonTapped: (int)ASCIICode;
{
    NSLog(@"you tapped button with %d", ASCIICode); 

}
```

Comment: pls let me know what is the use of  id<YourKeyboardControllerDelegate> delegate; here because i understand that we can get the tag of the uibuton when using this (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender

Comment: Look at my edit, please and let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ..how can i show text on the text field. i can convert the ascii value to string. but i request ur advice to show on the textfield

Comment: Also can this work on more than one field

Comment: You need set textfield's delegate to MainViewController. Then on -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField method you need to save current text field in some variable, lets say "currentTextField". When you detect buttonTapped you need to convert ASCII to NSString and then type currentTextField.text = [currentTextField.text stringByAppendingString:newChar], where newChar is result of ASCII to NSString conversion. You can set this keyboard to several textfields the same way - setting inputView and delegate. Hope that's clear?

Comment: whenever i click on the a button of keypad, the app crash with the error that selector not found. Trying hard but can fullfill this. Please check my code here - https://github.com/vikysaran/Application

Comment: how can I commit fix? (or just look at my edit)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code samples for creating custom keyboards. It seems like a nice solution:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7350-adding-subviews-custimize-keyboard.html