# customized keypad on the iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, custom-controls

i have requirement of creating a applicartion will different language other than English. I research over then internet and found i would have to create my own iphone keypad for this.

I found [this post very useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323928/code-sample-to-create-own-keyboard). I tried to make a custom keyboard but could not succeded. The application crashed as a press button of the custom keyboard. The button could not found its `TouchUpInside` event and crashes.

I know i am missing something and i am very close to this. Here is a sample application i made with XIB. Please anyone pull and install this [sample app](https://github.com/vikysaran/Application) and let me know what is the mistake i am doing. I will update the code and will push again for others.

---

Thanx for the reply. Its 3 version will be released with 3 different languages. There is no switching of the languages because versions are different. Arabic version will show arebic keyboard only,  French version will show french keyboard only and Farsi version will show farsi keyboard only. In my application above i have made a UIView that behaves like a keyboard on `[textview becomeFirstResponder];` After then i put a arabic keypad image as UIImageView as a subview to it, I will put many buttons to it and will assign tags of these buttons to ASCII values and will track then pn buttpon click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go for a sample app I made using xib.
I created a protocol that works for 2 different view controllers textfields.

https://github.com/vikysaran/Application

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a custom keyboard to use non-English languages.  Whatever you've found through random web searches, stop using them and look at the official documentation in the developer library.  In particular, [Internationalization Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i).

Comment: Internationalization is not my problem. But in this application i have to open keypad only in Arabic, French and Farsi languages for 3 different versions. Whatever the user's current location or locale, the keypad should open in a certain language only.

Please eleborate....

Comment: So your problem is not non-English keyboards, it's switching between different languages while an app is running.  iOS isn't designed for this.  Can you give some background on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: thanx for the reply. Its 3 version will be released with 3 different languages. There is no switching of the languages because versions are different. Arabic version will show arebic keyboard only,  French version will show french keyboard only and Farsi version will show farsi keyboard only.

Comment: Why are you building three separate versions?  Nothing you've mentioned so far can't be handled with a single application using the normal iOS internationalisation support.  You aren't supposed to build a separate application for each language.

Comment: its client requirement only. Im creating single app with localized variables but client wants 3 different apps. And they want 3 different language app in app store. accidently i pressed enter key in my previous comment. here I am explaining again as next comment.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. Its 3 version will be released with 3 different languages. There is no switching of the languages because versions are different. Arabic version will show arebic keyboard only,  French version will show french keyboard only and Farsi version will show farsi keyboard only. In my application above i have made a UIView that behaves like a keyboard on [textview becomeFirstResponder] After then i put a arabic keypad image as UIImageView as a subview to it, I will put near 45 buttons to it and will assign tags of these buttons to ASCII values and will track then 0n buttpon click

Comment: If you use the normal iOS internationalisation mechanisms, the appropriate keyboard will be used automatically.  You don't need to build your own keyboard.

Comment: it is done by creating custom keypad for every view that has textfield /textview.
The main issue was the farsi keypad. iPhone doesn't provide farsi interface and my client has requirement of Arabic, Farsi and french keypads.
Other 2 were ok but i had to create custom kepad for farsi language.
Thanks anyways...
earliest i will publish my code.