# How to customise the default keyboard in Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, uikeyboard

when we click the text field, the default keyboard or keypad not to be appear instead i need to display the custom keyboard..

### Did any one know the answer please post it..

Declared in 
UIResponder.h

### UIInputViewAudioFeedback  protocol.

Is this method correct or else there having any simple method to work out?

[image: Custom keyboard in xcode 5]

Comment: Are you looking to present the Number Pad keyboard instead of the Default keyboard, per your image?

Comment: he want some other options below a number pad i think.

Comment: yes i need the Number Pad keyboard as the above image.

Comment: @user3082253 please see my answer to display the Number Pad keyboard type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `protocol` for this for having a custom keypad appearing throughout the app. I have made it few months back and the stuff was working well. My requirement was to create a keyboard for `farsi` language, because `ios` does not have `farsi` in its language settings.

There is no need to make `protocol` if you want it in just 1 `viewcontroller`.

Here is my that thread:

[customized keypad on the iPhone Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760429/customized-keypad-on-the-iphone-application)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that I created that might help. Just fork it on GitHub and change the Punjabi characters to Myanmar. Most of the hard work is done for you :)

https://github.com/kulpreetchilana/Custom-iOS-Keyboards

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment you need the Number Pad keyboard.

Set your `UITextField` keyboardType property, either via Interface Builder or programmatically:

```
textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```